# “if it indeed is" or "if it is indeed"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I got confused on where should I put the word "indeed" in my sentence.

I have a sentence like:

> I think this apple is red, and if it indeed is, then we should eat it.

I feel really uncomfortable with "indeed" over there. But I don't want to delete it since I want to somehow point out "indeed"...

Any instructions? Thank you!

Comment: Either is fine, though I would prefer the way you wrote it. You could also say "I think if this apple is indeed red, then we should eat it." You might tell us more about "feel really uncomfortable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The positioning of *indeed* in the phrase "if it is" is fairly flexible. The following [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indeed+if+it+is%2Cif+indeed+it+is%2Cif+it+indeed+is%2Cif+it+is+indeed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindeed%20if%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20indeed%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20it%20indeed%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20it%20is%20indeed%3B%2Cc0) shows the occurrences of "indeed if it is", "if indeed it is", "if it indeed is", and "if it is indeed":

[image]

I'm not saying that all of them are correct, but "if indeed it is" and "if it is indeed" seem to be the clear winners.