# Where should I put "indeed" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

> I could definitely tell that his desire for reading was **indeed insane.**
>
> I could definitely tell that his desire for reading was **insane indeed.**

I've already saw [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109511/if-it-indeed-is-or-if-it-is-indeed),

and I've also googled it to find out where to put 'indeed', and I'm still confused because there are sentences which 'indeed' comes before an adjective, and also after an adjective.

Which one is correct between those two I wrote?

Comment: I think they're both correct. It's really all about where you want to put the emphasis.

Comment: You can put it in either place, but the first sounds more natural. Use the second to intensify the feeling.

Comment: Do 'His desire for reading indeed deserved to be called insane.' and 'Indeed, his desire for reading deserved to be called insane.' also mean the same?

Comment: Pretty much. The former emphasizes "deserved to be called insane" and the latter emphasizes the person's agreement in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical, but they have different meanings. To understand them, let's look at the first two definitions of the word *indeed*, according to the Oxford English Dictionary:

> **1.**
>
> **a.** In actual fact, in reality, in truth; really, truly, assuredly, positively
>
> **b.** Frequently placed after a word in order to emphasize it: hence, with n. = actual, real, true, genuine; with adj. or adv. = really and truly.

Your first sentence uses definition 1a. That is, "it was indeed insane" means "it really was insane." To me, this usage implies that, originally, you weren't sure it was insane (or thought it wasn't), but then learned something that confirmed that it was.

Your second sentence, I'd argue, uses definition 1b. Here, *indeed* is strengthening *insane*; "it was insane indeed" is similar to "it was really insane".

Basically, both are correct, and it's just a matter of which meaning you're going for.